# JQuery ajax POST string parameter, MVC action method get null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have seen quite a few posts online regarding this kind of problem and tried different approach, e.g. JSON.stringify the parameter, but none of them works on mine case.

I thought it should be a really simple and straight forward coding experience. But couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SendEmails').click(function () {
        var emails = $("#EmailList").val();     

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Requests/SendEmails',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'emails': emails },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And my action method is like:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SendEmails(string emails)
{
    return "Good";
}
```

I always get null in action method when I debug the code.

But if I change the url to this:

```
url: '/Requests/SendEmails?emails=' + emails,
```

and remove

```
data: { 'emails': emails },
```

it will work.

Anyone could point me what is wrong with the original code? I don't think .Net Core 2.x should make any difference right?

Thank you.

Comment: `type: "POST"` should be `method: "POST"`. Correct that and see if it works.

Comment: @Spokey `type` is an alias for `method`

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (your not stringfying the data)

Answer (score 10):

Finally, after tried many combinations I found below code works after changed:

1. make variable JSON.stringify
2. add [FromBody] in action method

Thanks for Arunraja's tips, [FromBody] is a must to have to read string type parameter from body.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SendEmails').click(function () {
        var emails = $("#EmailList").val();     

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Requests/SendEmails',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(emails),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        })
    })
})

[HttpPost]
public string SendEmails([FromBody]string emails)
{
    return "Good";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To pass primitive type in the body, then you have to add [FromBody] in front of your primitive type parameter in your WebAPI controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public string SendEmails([FromBody]string emails)
{
    return "Good";
}
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem make any difference, it is still null in the action method.